# Create special Matrix in mathematica

Tags: matrix

I want to generate the following matrix for any n:

```
      Table[A[i, j], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
```

Where,

```
      A ={{0,1,0},{0,0,2},{0,0,0}} when n=2;

      A={{0,1,0,0},{0,0,2,0},{0,0,0,3},{0,0,0,0}} when n=3;


      A={{0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,2,0,0},{0,0,0,3,0},{0,0,0,0,4},{0,0,0,0,0}} when n=4, and so on for any n.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

A[n_Integer?Positive] := DiagonalMatrix[Range[n], 1, n + 1]

A /@ Range[2, 4]//Column
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Bob Hanlon.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) + [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html):

```
ClearAll[sA]
sA[n_] := SparseArray[Band[{1, 2}, Automatic] -> Range@n, n + {1, 1}]
```

***Examples:***

```
sA /@ Range[2, 4] // Map[MatrixForm] // Row
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The following approach is easily adapted to other cases. (But Bob Hanlon's answer is the right one for the original question.)

```
makeMat[n_] := With[{
   zeros = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}],
   rules = (Rule[{#, 1 + #}, #] &) /@ Range[n - 1]
   },
  ReplacePart[zeros, rules]]
```

Comment: Many thanks Alan.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes like using `Module` to define local functions (more precisely, local symbols with `DownValues`) to use the ridiculous generality Mathematica provides for such definitions:

```
ClearAll[specialMatrix];
specialMatrix[n_Integer?Positive] := specialMatrix[n] =
  Module[{a, between = Between[{0, n}]},
   a[i_Integer?between, j_Integer?between] /; j == i + 1 = i + 1;
   a[_Integer, _Integer] = 0;
   Table[a[i, j], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}]]

specialMatrix[3]
(* {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} *)

specialMatrix[4]
(* {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

The memoization in the definition of `specialMatrix` is optional but may be worthwhile if you repeatedly use `specialMatrix` to generate large matrices.

Comment: Many thanks Pillsy.